# MapFragment update button position

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, mapfragment

I am encountering a rather specific problem. I have a `MapFragment` in my `Activity` in a `FrameLayout` so that the `Toolbar` overlays the map. This because the `Toolbar` needs to be animated off the screen sometimes and if it doesn't overlay the map there will be a gap.

Now when a device doesn't have valid `Google Play Services` the `MapFragment` will display a message and a button to update the services by default. My problem is that this message is shown at the top left corner of the map, which is below the `Toolbar`.

Does anyone have an idea on how to tackle this problem? Maybe check the validity of the `Google Play Services` myself and create some padding when it is not valid? Or is there an easy solution like setting some kind of gravity on the map so that the update message is centered.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add padding around the edges of the map using the GoogleMap.setPadding() method. Or create custom alertDialog which shows to user information about Google Play Services

example with dialog

```
GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int code = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
        if (code == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        //
        } else {
           AlertDialog alertDialog =
                 new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle).setMessage(
                       "You need to download Google Play Services in order to use this part of the application")
                       .create();
           alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: The `setPadding` method won't work since there is no map loaded, but the idea to use a dialog is good. I used it in a previous project with a note that I made the dialog impossible to dismiss (in case that this will be dismissed the user will be on an empty screen).

Comment: you should add .setCancelable(false)

Comment: or  .setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                                // finish activity or back to previous fragment
                            }
                        })

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have to check play services myself. However like lulian said `setPadding()` doesn't work. I think I'll go with the `Dialog` solution.